# It is possible to use microsoft identity with postgres and also db first?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to connect app with microsoft identity. DB is in postgresSQL, also i made my project db first and want to continue this way. To work with microsoft identity i need to have some additional tables in db but i dont want it after scaffolding in my db models, another problem is renaming every time class  `MyContexttDb : DbContext` to `MyContexttDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`.

Is there antoher way to make this solution better?